# SQL query to validate States with Country

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have 3 tables with below data.

1. COUNTRY - With 4 countries

| CountryCode | CountryName |
| --- | --- |
| USA | United States of America |
| CAN | Canada |
| IND | India |
| CHN | China |

2. STATE - With states defined only from 2 countries

| StateName | CountryCode |
| --- | --- |
| California | USA |
| Texas | USA |
| Kerala | IND |
| Punjab | IND |

3. LOCATION

| Name | StateName | CountryCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Loc_01 | California | USA |
| Loc_02 | Punjab | IND |
| Loc_03 | Punjab01 | IND |
| Loc_04 |  | USA |
| Loc_05 | Bihar | CHN |
| Loc_06 | California |  |

Expected output is for each location, categorize it based on below condition.

- If Location contains valid state name(i.e. State Name which exist in
  table `STATE`) and corresponding country is also mapped in 'STATE'
  then keep it as is.
- - If Location contains valid state name(i.e. State Name which exist in
    table `STATE`) and country code is null in `LOCATION` table then
    then keep it as is.
- If Location contains a state name which exist in
  `STATE` table but mapped with different country, then it will be
  marked as **INVALID**.
- If Location contains a state name does not exist
  in `STATE` table then keep it as is.
- If Location doesn't contain a
  state name, it will be marked as **UNDEFINED**

| Name | Derived Name |
| --- | --- |
| Loc_01 | Loc_01 |
| Loc_02 | Loc_02 |
| Loc_03 | INVALID |
| Loc_04 | UNDEFINED |
| Loc_05 | Loc_05 |
| Loc_06 | Loc_06 |

I need SQL/Redshift query for the same.

Comment: Hi - I’d recommend you normalise your data model so that you don’t duplicate your data like this. However, assuming you stick with your current design then you need to show what you’ve managed to write on your own and ask a focussed question on a specific issue you are facing. Unfortunately this is not a free code writing service

Comment: Why is Loc_03 INVALID? Punjab01 doesn't exist in the State table.

Comment: @TomBoyd, Punjab01is invalid because STATE table contains all the states belonging in a particular country. So all the states which belong to IND or USA are part of the STATE table. Any other state with countrycode which exists in STATE table should be marked as INVALID.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be with a CASE statement covering the specific situations you want to identify, and any condition with "keep as is" falls to the ELSE, something like this:

```
select
    name,
    case
        when l.StateName is null then 'UNKNOWN'
        when s.StateName is not null and s.CountryCode <> l.CountryCode then 'INVALID'
        else l.Name
    end as derived_name
from    
    location l
    left join
    state s on s.StateName = l.StateName
```